# Export faces from Picasa

Tags: automation, picasa, face-recognition

1. Is there any way to export croped detected faces images from normal
   images in Picasa?
2. Is there any way to export similar person not naming them(like
   person1 and person2 etc. and maybe with probabilities)?
3. Is there any way to detect only one person per folder?

Answer (score 4):

Once you have labeled each face within Picasa, there will be a file called `.picasa.ini` in the same folder as the photos. Its contents look like this:

```
[Contacts2]
a5719c14e1f43ecd=Bob;;
3df0fc0982a61960=Tom;;
[188698.jpg]
faces=rect64(4787040aa5044c1d),a5719c14e1f43ecd
backuphash=47212
[188766.jpg]
faces=rect64(49243a1b62da69d0),a5719c14e1f43ecd
backuphash=47212
[188804.jpg]
faces=rect64(283512ee998ed795),3df0fc0982a61960
backuphash=36479
[188803.jpg]
faces=rect64(778799bdf0c8f784),3df0fc0982a61960
backuphash=36479
[188812.jpg]
faces=rect64(28350000ae21dc8b),3df0fc0982a61960
backuphash=36479
[188806.jpg]
faces=rect64(44643314e5f5afd9),3df0fc0982a61960
backuphash=36479
```

You can use this data to calculate the coordinates of each rectangle you want to crop.

For more details on the `.picasa.ini` format, see this question:
[Automatic face detection using Picasa API to extract individual images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872112/automatic-face-detection-using-picasa-api-to-extract-individual-images)

Comment: But how automate face labeling procedure?